# VLAN-Subnets 1:1?

Tags: routing, ipv4, vlan, subnet

I often hear people saying that each VLAN is a subnet (or is associated with a subnet) but is that really true?
Assume I have 10 big offices. I will have a subnet for each office but only 2 VLANs grouping some computers, e.g. finance workers to be separated. Is that correct or I really should have subnets and VLANs in 1:1?

Comment: What actually do you mean by 1:1?

Comment: Like n:n ratio.  10 VLANS to 10 subnets.

Comment: Every subnet should have its own vlan, assuming the subnet is connected to an ethernet switch

Comment: Often it is said that VLAN can contain more than one subnet (http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/difference-between-subnet-and-vlan) or that VLAN can span across multiple subnets (e.g. group by MAC). Which is would I would do in the example I mentioned.

Comment: @MikePennington The problem I have is that some (Cisco forum) say it is not possible for two hosts to be on different subnets and same VLANs. However in books I read otherwise.

Comment: In most cases, there is no good reason to put multiple subnets in one vlan; just because you can doesn't mean you should

Comment: @MikePennington Ok, that answers something, thank you. And what about the statement that VLAN cannot be set over multiple subnets? I see contradictions here.

Comment: Give us a real reference or hyperlink to the quote please

Comment: https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/34441   Response no.8.

Comment: The quote you're referencing assumes no gateway for each subnet in that same vlan.  If you provide routed gateways for each subnet in the vlan, it is possible.  This is commonly called a "router on a stick" topology

Comment: @MikePennington I wonder why you do not put that as an answer? It does answer the question. Thank you

Comment: Answers are more work than comments... If nobody else answers,  I will post an answer after work.

Comment: "Assume I have 10 big offices. I will have a subnet for each office but only 2 VLANs grouping some computers, e.g. finance workers to be separated.". Why do you want to create subnet for each office and then grouping users using 2 VLAN? Are you by any chance talking about trunking, not actually VLAN? Because somehow, I can't see the point of creating subnet for each office and then you group users to only 2 VLAN. What actually do you want to achieve that created this question?

Comment: @Ron Vince: just to separate the network to smaller chunks. VLANs would be for specific users sitting in various offices. I do not even know if that is possible as there is just one main router and then switches in each floor and each office. I just started learning this..

Comment: As expected. This is actually about trunking. Trunking requires router-on-stick to be configured on the router's interface connected to switch, if the switches do not support L3. You can read about trunking for more details. In short, trunking (or trunk link) is using 1 physical link for many virtual links, of course one virtual link per VLAN.

Comment: @RonVince Thank you, I am going to read about that more.

Comment: Don't worry. What you imagine can be solved by using VLAN, trunking and router-on-stick. Anyway, router-on-stick is only needed when you have no L3 switch. Router-on-stick is to teach you the concept of a VLAN as a broadcast domain and it requires L3/routing device to communicate between different broadcast domain. Broadcast domain=subnet. In real life, L3 switch has become cheap that it is not worth it to use router-on-stick due to performance.

Comment: @MikePennington, there are cases for using multiple subnets per VLAN.  One site I have been at recently issues PI IP addresses directly to user workstations.  Leaving aside the NAT/PI discussion, in this environment, they use a second non-routable subnet in each VLAN for printers, copiers and other devices that may be discoverable on the local VLAN but don't require the use of a "real" IP address.

Comment: @ylearn I did qualify my one subnet per vlan statement with "in most cases"

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is generally a 1:1 mapping between subnets and VLANs because there isn't a very good reason not to.  You *could* have a big network with 1 VLAN, but why have a huge broadcast domain where all hosts see every broadcast when you can just separate each subnet with a VLAN? It's a waste of resources.

Subnets/VLANs are, more often than not, focused around similar uses (i.e. printer VLANs, workstation VLANs, etc.) and allowing for a single entry/exit point makes policy much easier to enforce on the VLAN/subnet as a whole. There are also [security implications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) that sprout up in shared layer 2 domains, so you would stand to benefit from segmenting traffic as much as possible.

Comment: And there are other Layer-3 protocols besides IP. (even v4 vs v6) There are places in the world where IPX still exists. (and appletalk and DECnet for that matter, but I'd say those are *very* rare, indeed.)

Answer (score 1):

### Technically there is not a direct link between VLAN and Subnet.

> "Assume I have 10 big offices."

I think this may be the confusion.

When you have offices connected with routers, the traffic flows through a L3 device.

Two network's on different sides of a L3 device is on different VLAN's(Physical) networks.

They may have the same vlan ID but they are not the same vlan.

If this was not the case every vlan in every company in the world would be the same vlan if they had the same vlan ID.